# FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'storage/emulated/0/DCIM/docs/myPdf.pdf' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a pdf document and write my data in that file. The data is a list of int or uint type. Able to do the same for images but not pdf or doc file. All permissions are given and it works for images. My code is below -

```
Future <File> createDocFile(Uint8List fileData, String type) async
{
  File file = new File(".pdf");
  if(await PermissionHandler.checkPermission(Permission.storage)!=true){
    Url.toastShow("Storage permission not found.");
    await Permission.storage.request();
  }
  else {
    await file.writeAsBytes(fileData);
    print("PDF SAVED IN DEVICE");
    Url.toastShow("PDF saved in device",Colors.green);
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you create a new file the device can't automatically find it. You'd have to manually tell the device to refresh for the files. Before you'd have to refresh all the files in the device for it to get updated which was very inefficient, but now you could just send the path of the file that you want to get updated. You can use the [media_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/media_scanner) plugin to do so.

Or If you wanna do it yourself with kotlin then here's the code,

```kotlin
private fun broadcastFileUpdate(path: String){
    context.sendBroadcast(Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,Uri.fromFile(File(path))))
}
```